# Python statsmodel output and Excel/Google Sheet output doesn't match

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statsmodels

I have a small dataset, for some reason, the output doesn't match with Excel's.

Here's what I did. I have to columns:

| Miles Traveled | Travel Time |
| --- | --- |
| 89 | 7.0 |
| 66 | 5.4 |
| 78 | 6.6 |
| 111 | 7.4 |
| 44 | 4.8 |
| 77 | 6.4 |
| 80 | 7.0 |
| 66 | 5.6 |
| 109 | 7.3 |
| 76 | 6.4 |

This is the output I get on Google Sheet:

|  | Slope | Intercept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Coefficient | 0.04025678079 | 3.185560249 |
| Standard Error | 0.005706415564 | 0.4669507938 |
| R Squared, Standard Error | 0.8615153295 | 0.3423088398 |
| F Stat | 49.76812677 | 8 |
| Regression SS / Residual SS | 5.831597265 | 0.9374027345 |

This output also matches with excel output.

However, when I do the following on statsmodel:

```
milesTravelled = [89.0, 66.0, 78.0, 111.0, 44.0, 77.0, 80.0, 66.0, 109.0, 76.0]
travelTime = [7.0, 5.4, 6.6, 7.4, 4.8, 6.4, 7.0, 5.6, 7.3, 6.4]

model = sm.OLS(travelTime, milesTraveled).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

I get the following:

```
                                 OLS Regression Results                                
=======================================================================================
Dep. Variable:            Travel Time   R-squared (uncentered):                   0.985
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared (uncentered):              0.983
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                              575.6
Date:                Mon, 01 Feb 2021   Prob (F-statistic):                    1.82e-09
Time:                        10:18:44   Log-Likelihood:                         -11.951
No. Observations:                  10   AIC:                                      25.90
Df Residuals:                       9   BIC:                                      26.20
Df Model:                           1                                                  
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                                  
==================================================================================
                     coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Miles Traveled     0.0781      0.003     23.991      0.000       0.071       0.085
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        2.179   Durbin-Watson:                   2.654
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.336   Jarque-Bera (JB):                1.033
Skew:                          -0.777   Prob(JB):                        0.597
Kurtosis:                       2.741   Cond. No.                         1.00
==============================================================================
```

As you can see, the values for standard error, R square etc. doesn't match Google Sheet/Excel at all. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to get an exact result summary like Google Sheet/Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `OLS` class doesn't include the constant term in the linear model.  You can use `sm.add_constant` to create the appropriate `exog` argument for `OLS`:

```
In [36]: milesTraveled = [89.0, 66.0, 78.0, 111.0, 44.0, 77.0, 80.0, 66.0, 109.0, 76.0]

In [37]: travelTime = [7.0, 5.4, 6.6, 7.4, 4.8, 6.4, 7.0, 5.6, 7.3, 6.4]

In [38]: X = sm.add_constant(milesTraveled)

In [39]: model = sm.OLS(travelTime, X).fit()

In [40]: print(model.summary())
/Users/warren/a2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:1603: UserWarning: kurtosistest only valid for n>=20 ... continuing anyway, n=10
  warnings.warn("kurtosistest only valid for n>=20 ... continuing "
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.862
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.844
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     49.77
Date:                Mon, 01 Feb 2021   Prob (F-statistic):           0.000107
Time:                        13:04:53   Log-Likelihood:                -2.3532
No. Observations:                  10   AIC:                             8.706
Df Residuals:                       8   BIC:                             9.312
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          3.1856      0.467      6.822      0.000       2.109       4.262
x1             0.0403      0.006      7.055      0.000       0.027       0.053
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        0.542   Durbin-Watson:                   2.608
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.763   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.554
Skew:                           0.370   Prob(JB):                        0.758
Kurtosis:                       2.115   Cond. No.                         353.
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```